# Can anyone explain what this means?

Tags: java, debugging, logging, websphere

Getting a weird line repeatedly in my logging file `SystemOut.log` of websphere.

```
HttpSessionCache/jmsPubUpd:  Discarding message of size:5000000; Discarding message of size:7394356
```

Environment:

```
WebSphere Platform 5.1
Host Operating System is Linux, version 2.4.21-47
Java version = J2RE 1.4.2
```

Is it harmful? Or can i ignore this line?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Session Replication is also enabled on websphere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time, please click the below link.

1. Discarding message of size:5000000;

the above message is used for the mail and websphere also.

It's the maximum size. When it's reaches then only it shows.

The default value of the RecoveryLogQueueSize is 5000000 bytes—5 megabytes.

If you use the Method: setRecoveryLogQueueSize(int size);

you defined the size. If you have time please click the link to read that

[Progress® SonicMQ® Performance Tuning Guide 8.0](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.0.0/Docs8.0/books/mq_tuning.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it have anything to do with session replication?